# Do you need to give up proxy objects in EntityFramework if you plan on serializing your POCOs?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am very confused. The whole point of proxy objects seems to be to improve performance by using lazy loading and better change tracking. But it seems that when you retrieve a proxied result from a Linq to EF query, and want to return that result over HTTP as JSON, you will get errors due to serialization, since there's a type mismatch.

All the solutions say to turn off proxies. Well what is the point of having them if you can't use them? What am I missing, how do I return serialized proxy objects, without instantiating a new non proxied anonymous type or POCO type (an object allocation) to mirror each object that I'm returning?

Comment: Serialization of proxied object will trigger lazy loading for all navigation properties recursively. Is it what you want to achieve? In highly connected model it can result in pulling out "whole your database".

Answer (score 0):

The performance improvement from using lazy loading/proxies is that you're not grabbing all the data at one time, making round trips to the database quicker and decreasing the likelihood of slowing down or even blocking other database operations.  If you know you're going to load all the data anyway, it's not necessarily a performance improvement.

That being said, there are some options if you can't use Include(...) (due to its limitations; e.g. GroupBy).

To load data with multiple trips to the DB, you can use the Load method on a reference or collection property to explicitly load the data without accessing it.  You can then disable proxy generation.
(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx)

e.g.:

```
context.Entry( entityObj ).Reference( "PropertyName" ).Load();
context.Entry( entityObj ).Collection( "PropertyName" ).Load();
```

If you want to utilize lazy loading w/ proxies for some properties but want to avoid WCF data contract serialization from attempting to lazy load others once the context is disposed, you can detach entities prior to leaving the DB context's scope.

```
EntityA a = null;
EntityA a2 = null;

using (var db = new TestEntities())
{
    a = db.EntityAs.Where( ea => ea.Id == 1 ).Single();
    db.Entry(a).State = System.Data.EntityState.Detached;

    a2 = db.EntityAs.Where( ea => ea.Id == 2 ).Single();
}

var b1 = a.EntityB; // c will remain null; no exception thown
var b2 = a2.EntityB; // blows up b/c it attempts to lazy load
```